# Modifying linux ping icmp payload

Tags: wireshark, packet-analysis, icmp

On analyzing ping request and reply from a windows system to Linux. It was observed that the windows ping request payload was

> "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwabcdefghi" with size 32 bytes

Could this behavior be mimicked in any other system like Linux, means could  someone create a ping request from Linux to impersonate as a windows ping request,

```
ping -t 128 -s 40 192.2.x.x ,
```

the above command in kali linux, gives ping request packet with icmp time stamp in linux (84 byte frame size)

[image]

Questions:

1. can os footprinting be done using icmp packet analysis and how
2. can someone send ping packets from linux with windows ping structure
3. how to modify icmp payload in linux to
   abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwabcdefghi
4. why ping packets in linux gives time stamp , and is there away to
   send them without it

New to wireshark, and icmp. Thank you so much for help

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations are off-topic here. This probably involves programming that is more appropriate on [so], but they are not going to hand you the code; you will need to show some work. You can ask about Linux configurations on [unix.se].

Comment: At the network level, there's only ICMP's echo request and reply mechanism: "ping" is just the conventional name for a program which sends them.  You can send whatever data you like in the packet, it's not impersonating Windows.  Many OS give a method to change the data, see man ping(1) on your computer.  But do read RFC 792 for the explanation.

Comment: `ping -s32 -p$(echo 'abcdefghijklmnop' | hexdump -e '"%02X"') 8.8.8.8` will get you close; `-s` specifies the size; `-p` specifies a pattern (in hex).  The standard Linux `ping -p` will only accept 16 bytes for its repeating pattern (`a-p`), though, whereas the Windows `ping` uses a 24-byte repeating pattern (`a-w`), so the Linux one is effectively sending `abcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnop`.  `nping` would probably be more-suitable, as it allows you to specify a full payload.

Comment: @jimbobmcgee  Does this means that i could tell that a ping initiator was a windows machine with 100 % confidence if the payload content was the one I mentioned? Thank you so much for replying.

Comment: No, not for certain.  You could *infer* it with some *limited* confidence, but you could still be wrong.  Just because the common Linux `ping` command doesn't give you an exact means to duplicate the pattern of a Windows `ping.exe`, doesn't mean that someone *couldn't ever* duplicate it with some custom ICMP-generating code.  Any requirement that has you trying to detect Windows machines based on their ping traffic alone is a requirement I would consider trying to get myself out of...